# In what currencies can I pay for the visa-on-arrival for Mauritania when entering overland?

Tags: visas, mauritania

I am currently in Agadir, Morocco and plan to enter Mauritania by bus travel. Opinions about Visa-on-arrival being available at the border differ, but I have not found someone having been turned back there so far. Online I can find the prices for the visa on arrival being 55 Euro / 65 USD.

Does someone know if they also accept Moroccan dirham?

Comment: http://www.veryhungrynomads.com/how-to-get-mauritania-visa-in-rabat-morocco/ this website says one can pay 660 dirham at the border. I will find out myself and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I crossed from Morocco to Mauritania on the 5th January, 2020 and paid with 55 Euro. There was one traveler in my bus that paid with Dirham. I was unable to check if USD is accepted but assume so. Note that 660 Dirham is currently almost 62 Euro, so if you have Euro it is better to use them unless you want to get rid of your Dirham.

I was able to change Dirham to Euro at the Albarid Bank in Dakhla, but it would have been far easier in other cities further North. The bank had only very few bank notes to pick from. Attijariwafa Bank told me they would need to see a Moroccan id card and they didn't have any Euro anyway. I did not see any money changer in the city. The airport may be another option. At the border there are many touts that offer money exchange but that would be my very last resort, as they are known for cheating, being pushy and offering bad rates.

For questions regarding the crossing the Supratours office near the beach shore (GPS 23.698243, -15.930753) is a good source of information, though only basic English is spoken. They offer a bus service that brings you to Nouadibou or Nouakschott.

Comment: Do you know what the cost was for a visa at the embassy in Rabat? It used to be around 150 EUR (I think the visa on arrival was slightly cheaper but not by much); glad to hear it's much more affordable now.

Comment: I don't know it first hand. This web site says 690 dirham. So it is more expensive than at the border. http://www.veryhungrynomads.com/how-to-get-mauritania-visa-in-rabat-morocco/